# MS Word - link to header of current section / relative referencing

Tags: vba, ms-word, reference

I'm working on a largeish document with multi-level headings, for a long set of test procedures. At the end of each procedure, there is a sign-off box. I want to add the section number and name to each sign-off box.

I researched (here, of course!) and wrote a macro to insert a reference to the heading of the current section, it appears to work fine:

```
Sub InsertCrossRefToSectionHeading()

    Dim RefList As Variant
    Dim LookUp As String
    Dim Ref As String
    Dim i As Integer

    
    LookUp = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\HeadingLevel").Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.ListFormat.ListString

    With ActiveDocument
        RefList = .GetCrossReferenceItems(wdRefTypeHeading)
        For i = UBound(RefList) To 1 Step -1
            Ref = Trim(RefList(i))
            If Left(Ref, Len(LookUp)) = LookUp Then Exit For
        Next i

        If i Then
            Selection.InsertCrossReference ReferenceType:=wdRefTypeHeading, _
                                           ReferenceKind:=wdNumberFullContext, _
                                           ReferenceItem:=CStr(i), _
                                           InsertAsHyperlink:=True, _
                                           IncludePosition:=False, _
                                           SeparateNumbers:=False, _
                                           SeparatorString:=" "
                                           
            Selection.TypeText Text:=vbTab
            
            Selection.InsertCrossReference ReferenceType:=wdRefTypeHeading, _
                                           ReferenceKind:=wdContentText, _
                                           ReferenceItem:=CStr(i), _
                                           InsertAsHyperlink:=True, _
                                           IncludePosition:=False, _
                                           SeparateNumbers:=False, _
                                           SeparatorString:=" "
                                           
            'Copy the formatting from the previous cell in the template table and apply to refrence text.
            Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCell
            Selection.CopyFormat
            Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCell
            Selection.PasteFormat
                                           
        Else
            MsgBox "A cross reference to """ & LookUp & """ couldn't be set" & vbCr & _
                   "because a paragraph with that number couldn't" & vbCr & _
                   "be found in the document.", _
                   vbInformation, "Invalid cross reference"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

However, it is a hard-linked reference to the heading that was the heading for this section at the time of running the macro. If I add a section, all references in the sign-off boxes after that section are pointing at the previous section, and it defeats the purpose of it.

Yes, my macro will make it much quicker to fix, but there will be a lot of rework every time I add a section to this evolving document. And yes, I could possibly even programmatically search the document for tables with "Test Record" in the top row, then delete Row 2 Cell 2 and insert the reference... but that's a lot of extra programming!... I've done a ton of VBA in Excel, but am new to it in Word. I guess I could leave the references until the very end... of this edit - but then I'll have to do it all again if the doc evolves in the future (which is very likely).

Is there any way to reference the heading of the current section?

Comment: Please note that “header” and “heading” refer to two entirely different things. The terms are not interchangeable. “Section” also has special meaning in Word - are you using it in the correct context in your question? Using the terminology correctly helps us to understand your issue, given that we don’t have the document.

Comment: I think if you were to update the cross-references via ActiveDocument.Fields.Update, you'd find the references are actually still pointing to the correct headings.

Comment: The first two comments are well-founded and macropod's may answer your problem. If not, look into using instead, a StyleRef field. Here is a link to my writing on this field: http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fields.htm#STYLEREF

Comment: @TimothyRylatt - yes, I was a bit lazy with the terminology. I'm referring to Headings, i.e.
1  Heading Level 1 ...
1.1 Heading Level 2.....
 Question updated, thanks.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesKenyon, looks like that worked! I'm using { STYLEREF "Heading 5" \n \w \* MERGEFORMAT } { STYLEREF "Heading 4" \* MERGEFORMAT } to get the heading number and text. I have to update the level depending on what level the doc is at, but that's easy enough. And now I'm going to look at the macro again and get it to read the level for me..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @CharlesKenyon, here's the solution (much simpler than my first attempt too!).

```
Sub InsertCrossRefToSectionHeading()
' Adds ref to the heading of the current section.
'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67200486/ms-word-link-to-header-of-current-section-relative-referencing
'http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fields.htm#STYLEREF

    CurrentHeadingLevel = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\HeadingLevel").Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.ListFormat.ListLevelNumber

    Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:= _
        "STYLEREF  ""Heading " & CurrentHeadingLevel & """ \w ", PreserveFormatting:=True
    Selection.TypeText Text:=" "
    Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:= _
        "STYLEREF  ""Heading " & CurrentHeadingLevel & """ ", PreserveFormatting:=True
    
    'Copy the formatting from the previous cell in the template table and apply to refrence text.
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCell
    Selection.CopyFormat
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCell
    Selection.PasteFormat
End Sub
```

Comment: Much easier than a macro would be to save your field as AutoText. You are reinventing the wheel. See http://addbalance.com/word/wordperfect.htm#StartPage